# swift iOS larger titles text with different colors

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to work out if there is away to have the following text DRN1 the DRN in black and the 1 in Red in the Navigation bar title

I currently use  the following code

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "DRN1"
```

it would be great if I could have 2 lines of text in large titles as on the second line i want now playing.

```
 self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Now Playing"
```

Comment: you can create your custom View with desired design and override titleView, like `self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.titleView = MyTwoLinesView()`

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik could you give an example?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik but what is inside MyTwoLinesView()?

Comment: inside MyTwoLinesView you can put everything you want, in your case there will be UILabel with numberOfLines = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add custom `UIView` and `UILabel` to the `NavigationBar`.

Code will look like this,

```
let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width ?? 200) - 125, height: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height ?? 150)) // Custom title view

let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: titleView.frame.size.width, height: titleView.frame.size.height/2))
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18.0)
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0


let titleString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"DRN1")   
let myRange = NSRange(location: 3, length: 1) // range starting at location 3 with a lenth of 1: "Strings"
titleString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: myRange) // MultiColor title

titleLabel.attributedText = titleString  
titleView.addSubview(titleLabel)


let titleLabel1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: titleView.frame.size.height/2, width: titleView.frame.size.width, height: titleView.frame.size.height/2))
titleLabel1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
titleLabel1.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 15.0)
titleLabel1.numberOfLines = 0

titleLabel1.text = "Now Playing"
titleView.addSubview(titleLabel1)

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView  //Add customView to navigationBar
```

The output will look like following image,

[image]